# Ember {{component}} custom component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, htmlbars, ember-components

I am new to Ember and noticed the following code in my Handlebars:

```
{{component sec.myCompRef secInfo=sec fields=model.myMap}}
```

Does Ember have some helper like `{{component}}`? If yes, how does it work?

I have generally seen custom helper:

```
{{my-helper}}
```

But that has the same name component hbs/js backing it?

But I am not aware of `{{component}}` helper.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Ember has [`{{component}}`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_component) helper which allows you to dynamically choose and render component via component name passed to `{{component}}` helper.

So, basically the usage is:

```
{{component componentName}}
```

You can of course pass arguments and data to it like you would do with casual component declaration:

```
{{component componentName model=whatever}}
```

So, in your case:

```
{{component sec.myCompRef secInfo=sec fields=model.myMap}}
```

- `sec.myCompRef` is the name of component to render (it has to match some existing component)
- `secInfo` and `fields` are parameters passed to component